# Parseley framework for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, frameworks, parsley

I recently came across a framework for as3 called "[Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/)". I haven't heard about this framework yet. Can anyone give me a quick overview about this framework. I have worked with Cairgorm and the [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/) framework for as3 before. Also a comparison with Mate framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsley is a micro-architecture much like Cairngorm.  It's strengths are in dependency injection/inversion of control (DI/IoC) and decoupled messaging.  It is significantly more lightweight and unobtrusive than older implementations of Cairngorm.  It is quite popular, actually, much like [Robot Legs](http://robotlegs.org).

In fact, as of Cairngorm v3, Cairngorm it was re-written to be an extension of Parsley.

Comment: In Cairngorm v3, it depends upon Parsley, so you get your IoC via Parsley.

Comment: Bottom line is this: It's robust, easy to use, easy to architect and it's been used to create several record breakingly huge Flex applications. 'nuff said :)

Comment: Agreed, @J_A_X.  I like it a lot.  It is small and not very opinionated, so I can use whatever pattern I want.  I like using it a lot :)